# How to know when to push a view controller? (Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions issue)

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing an issue with pushing a view controller (or setting view controllers) on the navigation controller. Although lots of questions have been asked about the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" issue mine is a bit unique.

The reason I receive this warning is because I am trying to push or set view controllers while another controller is already in transition. The result is not seeing the newest view controller and the current controller is not responding (seems it is even deallocated) as expected.

My navigation controller architecture consist of the main view controller having a navigation controller. From this view controller there are possible "paths" (like a main menu) where each can then push or pop internal view controllers or request the main controller to go to another branch (uses `setViewControllers::`). I believe this is quite a standard procedure and all works just great...

But then there is another input to the navigation controller that comes from the server. In some specific cases getting the data from the server I would like to push an extra view controller to the navigation controller. This also works fine by itself but if the user has triggered to push or pop the current view controller and if I get a response which should push an extra view controller before the transition is complete everything breaks as described above.

So my best idea on how to solve this so far is to create some locking mechanism so that this view controller is pending its presentation until all transitions are finished. But this would be quite a task at the moment: I can not use the delegate as the navigation controller delegate is set dynamically on some controllers due to the custom transitioning.

Any thoughts, ideas, solutions would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should wait for while another controller is already in transition.    Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906966/completion-handler-for-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontrolleranimated. that use block returns when transition complete. go for next

Comment: Not really, check again. That is an UINavigationControllerDelegate which I already mentioned. I would like to try to avoid that because some (insert some bad adjectives) person found it useful to merge the transition protocol with the UINavigationControllerDelegate and is already in use.

Comment: It seems you are attempting to push view controllers actively in response to a notification, therefore interfering with the current push/pop that may be in progress. May I suggest to take a passive approach instead, where the notification would merely fill a queue, and the UX can just query that queue and perform pushing at it's own pace?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly I should save this controller push request somwhere and then push it at some specific points such as user trying to present/dismiss another view controller via his input (pressing a button would suffice)? If so I have actually thought of that but not only it is not a very nice solution but even implementig this is nothing short but modifying most of the controller classes. You must understand this is not about presenting some add but requesting some vital inforamtion from the user related to the application itself..