# NSNotificationCenter not Working

Tags: swift2, ios9

I want to call a method by using NSNotificationCenter .They do not call in Swift 2.0. I am newer in Swift . Please help . Any help would be apperciated.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         let landingView = NewsViewController(nibName : "NewsViewController", bundle: nil)
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(landingView, animated: true)
    }
```

In my News Controller

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotification:", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

    }

    func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Why did you remove `self` form the notif center twice?

Comment: You are posting notification before add observer

Answer (score 1):

You called this method

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

before your observer's created. So please post your notification after this method `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(landingView, animated: true)` completed. You can refer this post:

[Completion handler for UINavigationController "pushViewController:animated"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906966/completion-handler-for-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontrolleranimated)

Hope that helps.