# ViewController object is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view controller.
1. ViewController (VC)
2. WebViewController (WVC)

In VC I click on a button and WVC is shown.
After successfully completing all tasks in WVC, I want to show VC and execute a particular function in VC.

Now, Storyboard contains some objects and add to VC using click and drag.
Initially, it has some values(not nil).
I Click on button, WVC is pushed, After completing all task in WVC,
VC is pushed.

Now some values in VC is nil.
error,welcome (`UILabel`, `UIView`) is nil...
And also is want to call a function in VC.
How it is possible.?

### Code

### ViewController.swift

```
class LoginController:UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var error: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var welocome: UILabel!

    ......

    @IBAction func BtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
     let webViewCnt = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewCnt, animated: true)
    }
    func doSomeProcess(){

    }
}
```

### WebViewController.swift

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self

    self.start()
}
 func start(){
      ---- do some process ----
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let ViewCont = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as UIViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewCont, animated: true)
        ViewController().doSomeProcess() // call viewcontroller doSomeProcess() function
       }
   })
 }
}
```

Comment: describe your issue in more clear way with relevant code you written for that.

Comment: @Eldhose the second paragraph is your question . What you want to convey please be clear.

Comment: implement delegate methods of webview `webViewDidFinishLoad` and perform push inside, now inside appeared vc perform your action in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: Why would you push `VC` again instead of pop from `WVC`?

Comment: @sCha how we can do it.?

Comment: @vaibhav  can you give a sample code

Comment: seems you are excepting completion handler check it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906966/completion-handler-for-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: you can use protocol for that. Protocol is best way to execute particular function from other VC to desired VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple your are pushing VC to WVC,
So logically after pushing WVC to NavigationController.
it added WVC to the top of Navigation Stack.
& it it better to pop this WVC from Navigation will automatically show VC with previous values.

use this

### ViewController.swift

```
class LoginController:UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var error: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var welocome: UILabel!
    var isBackFromWVC = false
    ......

    @IBAction func BtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
       let webViewCnt = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewCnt, animated: true)   
       isBackFromWVC = true
    }
    func doSomeProcess(){

    }
    func vieWillAppear(){
      if(isBackFromWVC){
        doSomeProcess()
      }
   }
}
```

### WebViewController.swift

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self

    self.start()
 }
 func start(){
      ---- do some process ----
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

         self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
       }
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to also call a doSomeProcess() function in VC.

Comment: yes bro,
after you popViewController from WVC,
your VC's viewWillApper() will call,
you can call doSomeProcess() method in that viewWillApper()

Comment: If view is appears , everytime doSomeProcess is called..iCant do that.

Comment: @EldhoseElias
i have added one flag isBackFromWVC
which will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to pop:**

In this start() method just replace a line `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
instead of pushing the ViewController.

```
func start(){
      ---- do some process ----
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let ViewCont = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as UIViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewCont, animated: true)
        ViewController().doSomeProcess() // call viewcontroller doSomeProcess() function
       }
   })
 }
```

**Reason:**

When you are pushing to any ViewController, The storyboard will create a new reference of ViewController and the OOP's says every object has its own properties and method so that's why your pushing view controller properties may be `nil` assume that your `username: UITextField!` text will be nil due to separate instance of ViewController.

For calling the function of your view-controller you have to implement the [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3) if it is not for every time else you may work in `viewwillappear`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, probably what you want is to dismiss `WVC` and go back to `VC`.

in `WebViewController`'s `start()`:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and after pop, you need to execute `doSomeProcess()` function. There're several ways to do this and I'll introduce one here.

in `ViewController`, implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationCOntrollerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewCOntroller) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    switch operation {
    case .pop:
        let to = toVC as! ViewController
        to.doSomeProcess()
    default:
        break
    }
    return nil
}
```

of course you'll need

```
self.navigationController?.delegate = self
```

inside `VC`'s `viewDidLoad()` as well.