# How to detect pop/push animation ended within a navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to implement a (like present/dismiss functions)

```
popViewControler:animated:compilation

pushViewController:animated:compilation
```

In a `UINavigationController` subclass.

I want to detect in my subclass every time a new UIViewController is poppet /pushed and the animation has ended and then call the callback.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you can use/handle the compilation

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906966/completion-handler-for-uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: you can use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Comment: thanks, didn't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UINavigationControllerDelegate**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

}
```