# Swift View Controller slides twice problem

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

i am very new to all the swift stuff and i hope somebody can help me with this problem

I have set up the following

[image]

- Tabbar Controler  with 1 Navigationcontroller

So if  i start the application everything is fine  and the view controller with the "Button" is loaded in tab 1

Now i want to navigate within tab1 to another view controller with a "label"

Thats what i did :

Connected the button to the new view controller with the label as "Show seque"

If i start the application and click on the button then the new view controller with the label slides and and shows the back button

-- > So everything is OK here in my eyes ..it slides only "once"

But if i add a UIBarButtonItem in the View Controller on the top left programatically and want to navigate programatically to the view controller with the label it is loading twice. I am using the following code:

```
@objc func settingsTapped() {
    
    
let new = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "new") as! NewViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(new, animated:  true)

    
}
```

The problem here is that the view controller is loaded always twice. It slides and slides again so i have to click two times to go back to the main view controller

Can anybody help me here please ?

I do not understand why this happens because if i click on the button with the "Show seque only" then it slides only once as expected.

Comment: How many times is settingsTapped called?

Comment: Hi Don ..only once ! I have also made a complete new test project and have exactly the same problem . First i thought i have made a mistake in my other project but  this is not the case

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't also connect the UIBarButtonItem to the new view controller with a segue?

Comment: No i did not do this.. How can i make a seque programatically to the view controller with the label ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201390/10116367

Comment: Hi thanx for the info but it does not help. I tried with self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true in viewdidappear. and false on the settingsTapped but it still slides twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have fixed the problem. Many thanx also for the answers here !!

This was really a hard "nut" and i have searched a long time how to fix this

It was sliding twice because while creating the UiBarButtomItem i used this

```
 leftbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsTapped), for: .allEvents)
```

I have replaced ".allEvents" with ".touchUpInside" and now it is working as expected and slides only once

```
 leftbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This works fine now.

I really do not know why .allEvents is producing a twice sliding